# Dalvik Error on Creating Signed APK

Tags: android, dalvik, apk

Trying to export a project to a signed APK.  Getting the following error.  I believe the AdMob jar file in my libs folder is the problem.  I'm targeting API Level 13.

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:294)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:295)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:232)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:217)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
>   Caused by: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:713)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:251)
>       ... 4 more

Many thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Well I deleted the Admob jar from my project's 'libs' folder, "cleaned" the project, closed Eclipse, recopied the AdMob jar file back to the project's 'libs' folder, cleaned again, and I was able to create the APK file.

I think this was the Eclipse equivalent of slapping your old box tv to get better reception...  Anyways, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I deleted the Admob jar from my project's 'libs' folder, "cleaned" the project, closed Eclipse, recopied the AdMob jar file back to the project's 'libs' folder, cleaned again, and I was able to create the APK file.

I think this was the Eclipse equivalent of slapping your old box tv to get better reception...  Anyways, hope this helps someone.